# Data type of reported properties for syncing IotCentral device properties of type toggle

Tags: java, azure, azure-iot-central

I am writing a device client for Azure IotCentral in Java. I have problems getting device twin properties to show as "synced" in IotCentral.
Specifically, I have a "toggle" property named "test".

I receive changes to the desired property in my device client.
The desired property has a value of HashMap{"value":true}.

When I report back the change as a reported property, the property does not show as synced in the IotCentral interface, but shows notice "No update for n minutes".

I suspect that my reported property does not have the correct format?

I tried

- key:"test", value: Boolean.true
- key:"test", value: "true"
- key:"test", value: HashMap{"value": Boolean.true}

None of this works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String connectString = "HostName=iotc-xxx.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=showcase1;SharedAccessKey=yyy=";
        DeviceClient client = new DeviceClient(connectString, IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT);
        client.open();
        client.startDeviceTwin(
                (status, ctx)->System.out.println("IoT Hub responded to device twin operation with status " + status.name()),
                null,
                (prop,ctx)->System.out.println("onProperty callback for " + (prop.getIsReported() ? "reported" : "desired") +
                        " property " + prop.getKey() + " to " + prop.getValue() + ", Properties version:" + prop.getVersion()),
                null);

        Map<Property, Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>> desiredProperties = new HashMap<Property, Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>>()
        {
            {
                put(new Property("test", null), new Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>((p,o)-> {
                    HashMap<String,Object> hm = (HashMap)p.getValue();
                    Boolean v = (Boolean)hm.get("value");
                    System.out.println("Received value for test: " + v);

                    try {
                        var hs = new HashSet<Property>();
                        hs.add(new Property("test", v));
                        client.sendReportedProperties(hs);
                        System.out.println("Sent reported property map: " + hs);
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Could not report property: "+ e);
                    }
                }, null));
            }
        };
        client.subscribeToTwinDesiredProperties(desiredProperties);
        client.getDeviceTwin(); // For each desired property in the Service, the SDK will call the appropriate callback with the value and version.
    }
```

When I execute the program and I change the toggle UI element, the program outputs this:

```
10:50:12.471 [MQTT Call: pumpshowcase1] INFO  c.m.a.s.i.d.t.mqtt.MqttDeviceTwin - Message received on DT DEVICE_OPERATION_TWIN_SUBSCRIBE_DESIRED_PROPERTIES_RESPONSE
 10:50:12.473 [MQTT Call: pumpshowcase1] INFO  c.m.a.s.i.d.t.IotHubTransport - Message with hashcode 1740719682 is received from IotHub on Tue Mar 26 10:50:12 CET 2019, method name is onMessageReceived
 Received value for test: true
10:50:12.486 [azure-iot-sdk-IotHubReceiveTask] INFO  c.m.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceIO - Message with messageid 7d034cd6-2eb3-4c9e-9946-9d14c7bc11a4 along with callback and callbackcontext is added to the queue, method name is sendEventAsync 
 Sent reported property map: [test - true]
10:50:12.493 [azure-iot-sdk-IotHubSendTask] INFO  c.m.a.s.i.d.t.IotHubTransport - Get the message from waiting message queue to be sent to IoT Hub, method name is sendMessages 
 10:50:12.983 [azure-iot-sdk-IotHubSendTask] INFO  c.m.a.s.i.d.t.IotHubTransport - Invoking the callback function for sent message, IoT Hub responded to message with status OK_EMPTY, method name is invokeCallbacks 
 10:50:13.022 [MQTT Call: pumpshowcase1] INFO  c.m.a.s.i.d.t.IotHubTransport - Message with hashcode 506690950 is received from IotHub on Tue Mar 26 10:50:13 CET 2019, method name is onMessageReceived
 IoT Hub responded to device twin operation with status OK_EMPTY
```

So what is the expected format for the reported property?
Is there documentation on this?

Comment: Have you seen the code in this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-connect-raspberry-pi-csharp#add-a-real-device

Comment: Thank you Alberto, that link is what I have somehow never been able to find, and provides the key fact that telemetry is sent as an event and not a reported property (counterintuitively, to me, as an "event" is a distinct significant occurrence rather than a continuous data point).